# save variables with original name

Tags: matlab

I wrote a simple function to save automatically some variables with their name

```
function savevariables(varargin)
    %1st argument varible1, 2nd argument 'namevar1', 3rd variable2, 4th 'namevar2', etc 

    for i = 1:2: length(varargin)

        savedata = varargin{1,i};
        namedata=genvarname(varargin{i+1});
        save(strcat('/home/.../path/',namedata),'savedata')

        clear savedata
        clear namedata

    end

end
```

The problem is that when I load the variables again in the workspace their name is savedata... I would like that they have their original name..

So assuming that I've 2 vectors

```
Test1 = [1 2 3 4 5];
Test2 = [4 5 6];
```

I call the function

```
function savevariables(Test1, 'Test1',Test2,'Test2');
```

I want to save the variable Test1 as Test1 and Test2 as Test2 in a way that when I load them again in the workspace I have variable Test1 and Test2..

Comment: You are saving it as the string `'savedata'`, try using `savedata` instead.

Comment: Error using save
Argument must contain a string.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Not as easy fix as I thought it would be.

Comment: Could you specify exactly what you want the result to be? Suppose you call `savevariables(myVar1,myVar2)`, do you want `myVar1.mat` containing a variable named `myVar1`, and `myVar2.mat` containing a variable called `myVar2`? And why do you want to use the name twice (instead of only for the filename or only for the variable name.)

Comment: I've edited my question with an example

Answer (score 4):

There are some nice helper functions that help you in this.

Especially: `inputname` will extract the variable name so you don't need to specify it again. 
and `evalin` will perform the in the parent workspace - so you don't need to reassign the variable.
`genvarname` should not be neccesary as you need to provide a valid variable name anyway.

let me show you an example:

```
function savevariables(varargin)
for i=1:numel(varargin)
    str = sprintf('save %s %s',inputname(i),inputname(i));
    evalin('caller',str)
end
```

Example usage:

1. Create sample variable: `my_sample = rand(10);`
2. Call: `savevariables(my_sample)`

There now should be a file `my_sample.mat` which contains a 10x10 matrix of random numbers. You could call `clear` and then `load my_sample`. Then if you call `whos` you should get following output:

```
  Name            Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  my_sample      10x10              800  double
```

or the call for the sample you give in the question would be:

```
savevariables(Test1,Test2)
```

Comment: +1 Nice solution. However, it should be noted that this function does not have the same structure as the one OP uses. Variables will here be saved with their variable name as file name, it is not supplied as an additional parameter.

Comment: I got the error:
Error using save
variable 'namevariable' not found

Comment: @user1884905 - the question was about asking so save "under the same name", so I thought I'd save giving the name twice.

Comment: @gabboshow - I'll add an example to the answer. Tell me if you still get an error.

Comment: Yes, I see now in the edited question that OP seems to want to use the variable name as a file name.

Comment: @bdecaf - thanks it works fine now, but if I want to save the variable to another location (not the current folder) I assume that I've to modify the second inputname(i) in something like strcat('/path',inputname(1)) right?

Comment: You are correct - but it's the first inputname. (first parameter of save is the location)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `eval` which is never the best option but I can't see a way around it. I'm sure there si one though. But this should work.

```
function savevariables(varargin)
    %1st argument varible1, 2nd argument 'namevar1', 3rd variable2, 4th 'namevar2', etc 

    for i = 1:2: length(varargin)

        namedata=genvarname(varargin{i+1});
        filename = strcat('/home/.../path/',namedata);
        eval([namedata, ' = varargin{1,i};']);
        save(filename, namedata)

        clear savedata
        clear namedata

    end

end
```

Call as follows:

```
savevariables(Test1, 'Test1', Test2, 'Test2')
```

Then when you `load test1` you will get a variable called `Test1` in your workspace

Comment: @gabboshow that's how `eval` works, it takes a string and runs it as matlab code. So `[namedata, " = varargin{1,i};"]` for example will create a variable for you whose name is your namedata and whose contents is your savedata. Try the code.

Comment: Although why is your `savedate` set to `varargin{1,i}` and not just `varargin{i}`?

Comment: @gabboshow Oh I see you mean the `"` should be `'`. My bad, busy coding in other languages. I just tested the code though. It does work exactly as described in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-struct` option of the `save` function. Then you can save `some_struct.foo` as a individual variable `foo`.

```
function savevariables(varargin)

% swap varargin(2 * k) and varargin(2 * k + 1) to use struct()
varargin = flipud(reshape(varargin, 2, []));

varargin(1,:) = genvarname(varargin(1,:));
s = struct(varargin{:});

for varname = fieldnames(s).'
  save(['/home/.../path/' varname{1}], '-struct', 's', varname{1});
end
end
```

If you run `savevariables(1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 4, 'd', 5, 'd', 6, 'd');` you will get six files `a.mat`, `b.mat`, `c.mat`, `d.mat`, `d1.mat`, and `d2.mat`.